# How To get Alt+Shift+Enter work in WebStorm?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, webstorm, hotkeys

I've been trying to solve it for almost 2 days already. I read all threads about tracking hotkeys down in windows 10 that i am using. No help. I tried killing all processes, closing all programs - result is only one: <kbd>Alt + Shift + Enter</kbd> not working in WebStorm/PhpStorm, that is supposed to apply quick fix.

There is no good way in Windows 10 to track what process uses certain hotkey...
I tried using Spy++ last 14 version, but it doesn't log that keypress at all.

Also, I googled all keywords I could imagine about WebStorm/changing that hotkey/etc - also no information. Many old topics, back in days when there was different hotkeys.

- <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> - opens menu for fixes
- <kbd>Alt + Shift + Enter</kbd> - supposed to apply quick fix, but it doesn't in my workaround.

**Fast Edit**:
just tried adding <kbd>Alt + Shift + Enter</kbd> to another action and it worked, so problem should be with WebStorm not firing Quick Fix somewhy. Is there any command in `Settings->Keymap` that responsible for that command? I can't find any.

Comment: Where do you see that `Alt+Shift+Enter`? On a popup that you are getting when hovering over a warning/error? It works there for me (when it's visible). Windows 10. Some screenshot (or much better a screencast) is welcome to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shortcut can't be re-mapped unfortunately, please follow [IDEA-217465](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217465) for updates.

Note that `Alt+Shift+Enter` shortcut is designed to work only when the popup is shown. Otherwise, the user does not know what action is applied. With `Alt+Enter` it is different because it does not change the code, just opens a popup.; see the comments in [IDEA-209202](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209202)

Comment: Oh, so this is how it works.... well, took many effort, time, googling to finally get this. So you can use Alt+Shift+Enter only when the hint is shown. But to get this hint you need to use mouse hover on error, cuz hint won't come up if i put cursor on error. So i need to hover with mouse then switch hands to keyboard and press Alt+Shift+Enter, kinda not convenient